# Created this procedure, when I execute I am not getting expected results

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have created this procedure and I am not getting all records out. It should print id, ssn and ValidSSN. ValidSSN should come from case statement where is checking if SSN is valid. Please could you let me know why?

Number of other records matches from table I am pulling from but no results for ValidSSN. So I would get:

> id - 12356
> ssn - 456454564(fake)
> ValidSSN -   NULL

And another 6 mil rows downstream.

```
create procedure ##Validate_SSN


as

begin
drop table if exists ##SSN_RangeList;
drop table if exists ##SSN_Results;

SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE  ##SSN_RangeList 
(
    [AreaCode] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [GroupCode] [tinyint] NOT NULL
)  

insert into ##SSN_RangeList
values
(1, 11),(2,8),(3,8),(4,13),(5,11),(6,11),(7,11),(8,94),(9,92),(10,94),(11,94)
,(12,94),(13,94),(14,94),(15,94),(16,92),(17,92),(18,92),(19,92),(20,92),(21,92)
,(22,92),(23,92),(24,92),(25,92),(26,92),(27,92),(28,92),(29,92),(30,92),(31,92),(32,92)
,(33,92),(34,92),(35,74),(36,74),(37,74),(38,74),(39,72),(40,15),(41,15),(42,15),(43,15),(44,15)
,(45,15),(46,15),(47,13),(48,13),(49,13),(50,2),(51,2),(52,2),(53,2),(54,2),(55,2),(56,2)
,(57,2),(58,2),(59,2),(60,2),(61,2),(62,2),(63,2),(64,2),(65,2),(66,2),(67,2),(68,2)
,(69,2),(70,2),(71,2),(72,2),(73,2),(74,2),(75,2),(76,2),(77,2),(78,2),(79,2),(80,2)
,(81,2),(82,98),(83,98),(84,98),(85,98),(86,98),(87,98),(88,98),(89,98),(90,98),(91,98)
,(92,98),(93,98),(94,98),(95,98),(96,98),(97,98),(98,98),(99,98),(100,98),(101,98),(102,98)
,(103,98),(104,98),(105,98),(106,98),(107,98),(108,98),(109,98),(110,98),(111,98),(112,98)
,(113,98),(114,98),(115,98),(116,98),(117,98),(118,98),(119,98),(120,98),(121,98),(122,98)
,(123,98),(124,98),(125,98),(126,98),(127,98),(128,98),(129,98),(130,98),(131,98),(132,98)
,(133,98),(134,98),(135,23),(136,23),(137,23),(138,23),(139,23),(140,23),(141,23),(142,23),(143,23)
,(144,23),(145,23),(146,23),(147,23),(148,23),(149,23),(150,23),(151,23),(152,23),(153,21),(154,21)
,(155,21),(156,21),(157,21),(158,21),(159,86),(160,86),(161,86),(162,86),(163,86),(164,86),(165,86)
,(166,86),(167,86),(168,86),(169,86),(170,86),(171,86),(172,86),(173,86),(174,86),(175,86),(176,86)
,(177,86),(178,86),(179,86),(180,86),(181,86),(182,86),(183,86),(184,84),(185,86),(186,86),(187,84)
,(188,86),(189,84),(190,84),(191,84),(192,84),(193,84),(194,84),(195,84),(196,84),(197,84),(198,84)
,(199,84),(200,84),(201,84),(202,84),(203,84),(204,84),(205,84),(206,84),(207,84),(208,84),(209,84)
,(210,84),(211,84),(212,89),(213,89),(214,89),(215,89),(216,89),(217,87),(218,87),(219,87),(220,87)
,(221,11),(222,11),(223,99),(224,99),(225,99),(226,99),(227,99),(228,99),(229,99),(230,99),(231,99)
,(232,57),(233,57),(234,55),(235,55),(236,55),(237,99),(238,99),(239,99),(240,99),(241,99),(242,99)
,(243,99),(244,99),(245,99),(246,99),(247,99),(248,99),(249,99),(250,99),(251,99),(252,99),(253,99)
,(254,99),(255,99),(256,99),(257,99),(258,99),(259,99),(260,99),(261,99),(262,99),(263,99),(264,99)
,(265,99),(266,99),(267,99),(268,17),(269,17),(270,15),(271,15),(272,15),(273,15),(274,15),(275,15)
,(276,15),(277,15),(278,15),(279,15),(280,15),(281,15),(282,15),(283,15),(284,15),(285,15),(286,15)
,(287,15),(288,15),(289,15),(290,15),(291,15),(292,15),(293,15),(294,15),(295,15),(296,15),(297,15)
,(298,15),(299,15),(300,15),(301,15),(302,15),(303,37),(304,37),(305,37),(306,35),(307,35),(308,35)
,(309,35),(310,35),(311,35),(312,35),(313,35),(314,35),(315,35),(316,35),(317,35),(318,11),(319,11)
,(320,11),(321,11),(322,11),(323,11),(324,11),(325,11),(326,11),(327,11),(328,11),(329,11),(330,11)
,(331,11),(332,11),(333,11),(334,11),(335,8),(336,8),(337,8),(338,8),(339,8),(340,8),(341,8),(342,8)
,(343,8),(344,8),(345,8),(346,8),(347,8),(348,8),(349,8),(350,8),(351,8),(352,8),(353,8),(354,8)
,(355,8),(356,8),(357,8),(358,8),(359,8),(360,8),(361,8),(362,39),(363,37),(364,37),(365,37),(366,37)
,(367,37),(368,37),(369,37),(370,37),(371,37),(372,37),(373,37),(374,37),(375,37),(376,37),(377,37)
,(378,37),(379,37),(380,37),(381,37),(382,37),(383,37),(384,37),(385,37),(386,37),(387,33),(388,33)
,(389,33),(390,33),(391,33),(392,33),(393,33),(394,31),(395,31),(396,31),(397,31),(398,31),(399,31)
,(400,73),(401,73),(402,73),(403,73),(404,73),(405,71),(406,71),(407,71),(408,99),(409,99),(410,99)
,(411,99),(412,99),(413,99),(414,99),(415,99),(416,67),(417,67),(418,67),(419,67),(420,67)
,(421,65),(422,65),(423,65),(424,65),(425,99),(426,99),(427,99),(428,99),(429,99),(430,99),(431,99)
,(432,99),(433,99),(434,99),(435,99),(436,99),(437,99),(438,99),(439,99),(440,27),(441,27),(442,27)
,(443,27),(444,27),(445,27),(446,27),(447,27),(448,25),(449,99),(450,99),(451,99),(452,99),(453,99)
,(454,99),(455,99),(456,99),(457,99),(458,99),(459,99),(460,99),(461,99),(462,99),(463,99),(464,99)
,(465,99),(466,99),(467,99),(468,55),(469,55),(470,55),(471,55),(472,55),(473,55),(474,55),(475,55)
,(476,55),(477,55),(478,41),(479,41),(480,41),(481,41),(482,41),(483,41),(484,39),(485,39),(486,29)
,(487,29),(488,29),(489,29),(490,29),(491,29),(492,29),(493,29),(494,29),(495,29),(496,27),(497,27)
,(498,27),(499,27),(500,27),(501,37),(502,35),(503,45),(504,43),(505,57),(506,57),(507,57),(508,55)
,(509,33),(510,31),(511,31),(512,31),(513,31),(514,31),(515,31),(516,49),(517,49),(518,87),(519,85)
,(520,61),(521,99),(522,99),(523,99),(524,99),(525,99),(526,99),(527,99),(528,99),(529,99),(530,99)
,(531,71),(532,71),(533,69),(534,69),(535,69),(536,69),(537,69),(538,69),(539,69),(540,81),(541,81)
,(542,81),(543,81),(544,79),(545,99),(546,99),(547,99),(548,99),(549,99),(550,99),(551,99),(552,99)
,(553,99),(554,99),(555,99),(556,99),(557,99),(558,99),(559,99),(560,99),(561,99),(562,99),(563,99)
,(564,99),(565,99),(566,99),(567,99),(568,99),(569,99),(570,99),(571,99),(572,99),(573,99),(574,61)
,(575,99),(576,99),(577,53),(578,51),(579,51),(580,39),(581,99),(582,99),(583,99),(584,99),(585,99)
,(586,67),(587,99),(588,7),(589,99),(590,99),(591,99),(592,99),(593,99),(594,99),(595,99),(596,92)
,(597,92),(598,90),(599,90),(600,99),(601,99),(602,85),(603,85),(604,85),(605,85),(606,83),(607,83)
,(608,83),(609,83),(610,83),(611,83),(612,83),(613,83),(614,83),(615,83),(616,83),(617,83),(618,83)
,(619,83),(620,83),(621,83),(622,83),(623,83),(624,83),(625,83),(626,83),(627,29),(628,29),(629,27)
,(630,27),(631,27),(632,27),(633,27),(634,27),(635,27),(636,27),(637,27),(638,27),(639,27),(640,27)
,(641,27),(642,27),(643,27),(644,27),(645,27),(646,19),(647,19),(648,56),(649,54),(650,60),(651,60)
,(652,60),(653,58),(654,36),(655,36),(656,36),(657,34),(658,34),(659,22),(660,22),(661,22),(662,22)
,(663,20),(664,20),(665,20),(667,48),(668,46),(669,46),(670,46),(671,46),(672,46),(673,46),(674,46)
,(675,46),(676,20),(677,20),(678,20),(679,20),(680,27),(681,24),(682,22),(683,22),(684,22),(685,22)
,(686,22),(687,22),(688,22),(689,22),(690,22),(691,16),(692,16),(693,16),(694,16),(695,14),(696,14)
,(697,14),(698,14),(699,14),(700,18),(701,18),(702,18),(703,18),(704,18),(705,18),(706,18),(707,18)
,(708,18),(709,18),(710,18),(711,18),(712,18),(713,18),(714,18),(715,18),(716,18),(717,18),(718,18)
,(719,18),(720,18),(721,18),(722,18),(723,18),(724,28),(725,18),(726,18),(727,10),(728,14),(729,26)
,(730,26),(731,24),(732,24),(733,24),(750,18),(751,16),(752,7),(753,7),(754,7),(755,5),(756,12)
,(757,12),(758,12),(759,10),(760,10),(761,10),(762,10),(763,10),(764,23),(765,21),(766,96),(767,96)
,(768,96),(769,96),(770,94),(771,94),(772,94)



declare @ValidSSN varchar(50) = null
declare @ssn nVARCHAR(50) = null
declare @id bigint = null

SELECT 
        s.SSN,id,
        CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(s.ssn, '-', '')) <> 1 OR Sequence = 0 OR HighGroup = 0 THEN 'Invalid SSN' 
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN Groupcode % 2 = 1 THEN --odd groupcode 
                CASE WHEN GroupCode <10 THEN 
                    CASE WHEN HighGroup % 2 = 1 AND HighGroup <= GroupCode THEN 'Valid SSN' 
                    ELSE 'Invalid SSN' 
                    END
                ELSE
                    CASE WHEN HighGroup % 2 = 0 THEN 'Valid SSN' 
                    WHEN HighGroup % 2 = 1 THEN 
                        CASE WHEN HighGroup <= GroupCode THEN 'Valid SSN' ELSE 'Invalid SSN' END
                    END
                END
            ELSE --even groupcode
                CASE WHEN GroupCode >= 10 THEN
                    CASE WHEN HighGroup %2 =1 THEN
                        CASE WHEN HighGroup <=9 THEN 'Valid SSN' ELSE 'Invalid SSN' END
                    WHEN HighGroup %2 = 0 THEN
                        CASE WHEN HighGroup <= GroupCode THEN 'Valid SSN' ELSE 'Invalid SSN' END
                    END
                ELSE
                    CASE WHEN HighGroup %2 =1 THEN
                        CASE WHEN HighGroup <=9 THEN 'Valid SSN' ELSE 'Invalid SSN' END
                    WHEN HighGroup %2 = 0 THEN 
                        CASE WHEN HighGroup >=10 THEN 'Valid SSN' 
                        WHEN HighGroup < 10 THEN 
                            CASE WHEN HighGroup <= GroupCode THEN 'Valid SSN' ELSE 'Invalid SSN' END
                        END
                    END
                END
            END
        END ValidSSN 
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    LEFT(REPLICATE('0', 9 - LEN(LTRIM(REPLACE(@ssn, '-', '')))) + REPLACE(@ssn, '-', ''), 3) Area,
    SUBSTRING(REPLICATE('0', 9 - LEN(LTRIM(REPLACE(@ssn, '-', '')))) + REPLACE(@ssn, '-', ''), 4, 2) HighGroup,
    RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 9 - LEN(REPLACE(@ssn, '-', ''))) + REPLACE(@ssn, '-', ''), 4) Sequence,
    REPLICATE('0', 9 - LEN(REPLACE(@ssn, '-', ''))) + REPLACE(@ssn, '-', '') SSN
) v
LEFT JOIN ##SSN_RangeList sr
ON v.Area = CAST(sr.AreaCode AS VARCHAR(3)) 
join [infoarmor_secure].[subscribers]s on s.ssn = s.ssn

print @id
print @ssn
print @ValidSSN 
end
;
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... I think your key initial problem is this part of the FROM clause

```
join [infoarmor_secure].[subscribers]s on s.ssn = s.ssn
```

... noting the `on s.ssn = s.ssn` at the end. At a minimum I'd guess it should be `on v.ssn = s.ssn`

Also be wary of the expressions like

```
SELECT REPLICATE('0', 9 - LEN(REPLACE(@ssn, '-', ''))) + REPLACE(@ssn, '-', '') SSN;
```

If `@ssn` is 9 characters or less, that's OK - but if it's 10 or longer, it will result in the SSN being NULL (see my example below). This is because the first part would be NULL (e.g., `SELECT REPLICATE('0',-1)` results in NULL).

Several other issues

- It's not clear what you want with variables `@id, @ssn, @ValidSSN` there - you're not setting them so the prints at the end will always print nulls/blanks.
- Strongly consider whether you want to use 'global' temporary tables (and the procedure) e.g., those starting with ##. These are accessible by other processes. For example, if you run your process above twice (e.g., in two windows), the second process would probably delete the tables from the first process. Instead, temp tables are typically done with a single # e.g., `CREATE TABLE #SSN_RangeList` - these are limited to the current scope (e.g., the procedure and things called by the procedure).

Anyway, for testing purposes, I tried to simplify your code a bit to start with

- I removed some extraneous stuff from your code like the extra table, irrelevant fields, links to the infoarmor_secure table which we don't know about, etc
- I *did* create the temporary table #SSN_RangeList with data from above, but haven't included it below as it's just too repetitive
- Did a few tweaks to still get the values from the changes I made (e.g., changed s.SSN to v.SSN)
- Added an Orig_SSN field at the start to report the original SSN variable, in case the processing changed it

```
declare @ssn NVARCHAR(50) = '456454564';

SELECT 
        @ssn AS Orig_SSN,
        v.SSN, 
        -- id,
        CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(v.ssn, '-', '')) <> 1 OR Sequence = 0 OR HighGroup = 0 THEN 'Invalid SSN' 
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN Groupcode % 2 = 1 THEN --odd groupcode 
                CASE WHEN GroupCode <10 THEN 
                    CASE WHEN HighGroup % 2 = 1 AND HighGroup <= GroupCode THEN 'Valid SSN' 
                    ELSE 'Invalid SSN' 
                    END
                ELSE
                    CASE WHEN HighGroup % 2 = 0 THEN 'Valid SSN' 
                    WHEN HighGroup % 2 = 1 THEN 
                        CASE WHEN HighGroup <= GroupCode THEN 'Valid SSN' ELSE 'Invalid SSN' END
                    END
                END
            ELSE --even groupcode
                CASE WHEN GroupCode >= 10 THEN
                    CASE WHEN HighGroup %2 =1 THEN
                        CASE WHEN HighGroup <=9 THEN 'Valid SSN' ELSE 'Invalid SSN' END
                    WHEN HighGroup %2 = 0 THEN
                        CASE WHEN HighGroup <= GroupCode THEN 'Valid SSN' ELSE 'Invalid SSN' END
                    END
                ELSE
                    CASE WHEN HighGroup %2 =1 THEN
                        CASE WHEN HighGroup <=9 THEN 'Valid SSN' ELSE 'Invalid SSN' END
                    WHEN HighGroup %2 = 0 THEN 
                        CASE WHEN HighGroup >=10 THEN 'Valid SSN' 
                        WHEN HighGroup < 10 THEN 
                            CASE WHEN HighGroup <= GroupCode THEN 'Valid SSN' ELSE 'Invalid SSN' END
                        END
                    END
                END
            END
        END ValidSSN 
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    LEFT(REPLICATE('0', 9 - LEN(LTRIM(REPLACE(@ssn, '-', '')))) + REPLACE(@ssn, '-', ''), 3) Area,
    SUBSTRING(REPLICATE('0', 9 - LEN(LTRIM(REPLACE(@ssn, '-', '')))) + REPLACE(@ssn, '-', ''), 4, 2) HighGroup,
    RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 9 - LEN(REPLACE(@ssn, '-', ''))) + REPLACE(@ssn, '-', ''), 4) Sequence,
    REPLICATE('0', 9 - LEN(REPLACE(@ssn, '-', ''))) + REPLACE(@ssn, '-', '') SSN
) v
LEFT JOIN #SSN_RangeList sr
ON v.Area = CAST(sr.AreaCode AS VARCHAR(3));
```

The results of that select is

```
Orig_SSN     SSN        ValidSSN
456454564    456454564  Valid SSN
```

If I run the above but tweak the @ssn to be something different, I also get the various valid and invalid SSNs e.g.,

```
Orig_SSN     SSN        ValidSSN
156454564    156454564  Invalid SSN


Orig_SSN     SSN        ValidSSN
11456454564  NULL       Invalid SSN
```

Note that in the last one the formula to split the SSN returned NULL. I suggest you need to be really careful about these and have a large list of valid SSNs and invalid SSNs to check your processing works correctly.

Finally, some additional tips

- You're creating a temporary table #SSN_RangeList with column `areacode` as a number, then the only thing you do with it is convert it to a string within a join. Consider making it a string to start with.
- CASE expressions cascade - I find them a lot easier to read when they're done that way (rather than nested CASEs similar to nested IFs) - though this is personal preference.

Below is an example of a CASE expression that I tried to transpose from your above. I agree though it's still not 100% readable.

```
SELECT 
        @ssn AS Orig_SSN,
        v.SSN, 
        -- id,
        CASE 
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(v.ssn, '-', '')) <> 1 OR Sequence = 0 OR HighGroup = 0 THEN 'Invalid SSN' 
            -- Odd groupcodes
            WHEN Groupcode % 2 = 1 AND GroupCode < 10 AND HighGroup % 2 = 1 AND HighGroup <= GroupCode THEN 'Valid SSN' 
            WHEN Groupcode % 2 = 1 AND GroupCode < 10 THEN 'Invalid SSN' 
            WHEN Groupcode % 2 = 1 AND HighGroup % 2 = 0 THEN 'Valid SSN'
            WHEN Groupcode % 2 = 1 AND HighGroup % 2 = 1 AND HighGroup <= GroupCode THEN 'Valid SSN'
            WHEN Groupcode % 2 = 1 AND HighGroup % 2 = 1 THEN 'Invalid SSN' 
            -- Even groupcodes
            WHEN GroupCode >= 10 AND HighGroup % 2 = 1 AND HighGroup <= 9 THEN 'Valid SSN'
            WHEN GroupCode >= 10 AND HighGroup % 2 = 1 THEN 'Invalid SSN'
            WHEN GroupCode >= 10 AND HighGroup % 2 = 0 AND HighGroup <= GroupCode THEN 'Valid SSN'
            WHEN GroupCode >= 10 AND HighGroup % 2 = 0 THEN 'Invalid SSN'
            WHEN HighGroup % 2 = 1 AND HighGroup <= 9 THEN 'Valid SSN'
            WHEN HighGroup % 2 = 1 THEN 'Invalid SSN'
            WHEN HighGroup % 2 = 0 AND HighGroup >= 10 THEN 'Valid SSN' 
            WHEN HighGroup % 2 = 0 AND HighGroup < 10 AND HighGroup <= GroupCode THEN 'Valid SSN'
            WHEN HighGroup % 2 = 0 AND HighGroup < 10 THEN 'Invalid SSN'
            ELSE NULL END AS ValidSSN
```

Comment: Thank you so much @seanb, this is really helpful. So records from table ##SSN_RangeList are from SSA's website, way how they create and assign SSN's to people etc. I really appreciate your help, Simplifying the code is always better choice, honestly was looking at this for last two days and came back tonight to work on it. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: So reason I added id in original code is to report all records where SSN is invalid, and source for ID and SSN for data records is table join [infoarmor_secure].[subscribers]s on s.ssn = s.ssn. So pint of this proc would be to pull all records where SSN is not valid and send report to business side for corrections.

Comment: Ah I completely agree with including the ID etc - you need to be able to refer back to your data set. However, I commented it out in the above code as I didn't have the table [infoarmor_secure].[subscribers] where the ID was taken from. However, there are things you can remove there - it is worth checking what you actually need. In my answer I removed a lot of things so as to focus on what I thought were key issues. You should probably also remove the column I added Orig_SSN as it's not *needed*, but I put it in to demonstrate the function can make the SSNs NULL,

Comment: thank you so much for taking your time and looking at this, it did bug me for few days for sure.